# ref not available in HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ref

I have a reusable wrapper component which like this:

```
import { FC, HTMLAttributes } from "react";

const Wrapper: FC<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> = ({
  children,
  className,
  ...props
}) => (
  <div className={`h-[90vh] ${className ? className : ""}`} {...props}>
    {children}
  </div>
);

export default Wrapper;
```

But I can't add the `ref` prop to the component.

```
<Wrapper ref={ref} ...

Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
```

What typescript type should I use for the `Wrapper` component and add the ref prop without an error?

Comment: I would try `DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>` or `IntrinsicAttributes & HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use `FC` type, then you'll need to use `ComponentPropsWithRef<"div">` type for props. (don't forget to wrap component in `forwardRef` or ref won't work)

Alternatively, you can omit `FC` type and just define component like this:

```
import React, { forwardRef, ComponentPropsWithoutRef } from "react";

const Wrapper = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div">>(({
  children,
  className,
  ...props
}, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} className={`h-[90vh] ${className ? className : ""}`} {...props}>
    {children}
  </div>
));
```

This way you will be able to pass ref to the component and it will be typechecked.